# Calculate adjacency matrices in java

Tags: java, math, matrix

Basically I need to query the user for a matrix. Then I need to find A^2, A^3, A^4... and so on (where A is the matrix). Then I need to find the sum A + A^2 + A^3 ... etc up to 6.

So far this is what I've done

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, l, k, sum   =   0   ;
        int matrixAColumnSize         ;
        int matrixARowSize            ;
        double numberOfNodes             ;

        // Querying user for matrix size
        matrixARowSize      =   Tools.queryForInt("Enter the row size of Matrix A: ") ;
        matrixAColumnSize   =   Tools.queryForInt("Enter the column size of Matrix A: ") ;

        // Creating Matrices
        double matrixA[][]       =   new double[matrixARowSize][matrixAColumnSize] ;
        double finalMatrix[][]   =   new double [matrixARowSize][matrixAColumnSize] ;
        double tempMatrix[][]    =   new double[matrixARowSize][matrixAColumnSize] ;

        numberOfNodes   =   Tools.queryForInt("Enter by how much you'd like to raise to the power: ") ;

        // Creating Matrix A
        for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) {
                matrixA[i][j] = Tools.queryForInt("Enter element in Matrix A" + (i+1) + "," + (j+1) + ": " ) ; }}

        // Math
        for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) 
            {
                { 
                sum += Math.pow(matrixA[i][j], numberOfNodes) ;
                }

                finalMatrix[i][j] = sum ;
                sum = 0;

            }} 
        //Printing out matrix
        System.out.println("Final: ") ;

        for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) 
                System.out.print(finalMatrix[i][j] + "\t") ;

            System.out.println();
}
```

}
}

And its not working... :( lol

PS: Tools.queryForInt is a method I created to query the user...

The program itself IS working, but I am getting incorrect results. For instance,

```
2 2    *  2 2    =   8 8
2 2       2 2        8 8
```

The program would give me

```
4 4
4 4
```

So when I raise to the power of 2 it simply raises everything in the array by 2...

Comment: Also, i thought of adding a temp matrix thats why is there...

Comment: Why do you say that it's not working? How so? Are you getting incorrect results? Are you getting error messages?

Comment: What did you learn when you stepped through this with a debugger?

Comment: And you do realise that to raise a matrix to the `n`th power, you don't just raise each individual element to the `n`th power, right?  If not, then I would suggest you read up on the mathematics involved.

Comment: I have written a program that multiplies matrices but this is different because I need to raise to the power. How would I go about to multiply A*A*A is my real question.... @DavidWallace

Comment: If you have written a program that multiplies matrices, then why are you asking how to work out `A*A*A` ?  I don't understand the difficulty.  Just include your matrix multiplication method and call it repeatedly from here.

Comment: I've tried that it doesn't work. It just gives me double the amount. It basically would give me ((sum+matrixA[i][j]*matrixA[i][j])*(sum +matrixA[i][j]*matrixA[i][j])) if user inputs a 2 for numberOfNodes. @DavidWallace

Comment: Then you're calling it wrong.  And if you post that attempt, I can help you find the problem.  But really, there is no way to work out `A^6` (for example) than by repeatedly multiplying `A` by itself (although you can cut down on the number of multiplications by way of a few optimisations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are calculating the matrices is incorrect. Actually you are calculating powers of individual matrix element. 
Before multiplying a matrix, you should check their dimensions. for AxB number of columns in A should be equal to number of columns in B. Since you are multiplying a matrix to itself, it should be a square matrix.

This is the code i use to multiply two matrices. you may modify this code to suit your requirement. I would suggest to call this module recursively or iteratively

```
for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
  for(int j=0;i<col;i++){
    for(int k=0;i<row;i++){
      matrix[i][j]+=(A[i][k]*B[k][j]);
    } 
  }
}
```